# Android Using Retrofit and OkHttp to get Endpoints

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit, okhttp

I have a project setup. https://github.com/Axiom1999/Iron-Banner-Companion/blob/master/app/src/main/java/me/axiom/aapp/ironbannercompanion/

And I have a button which I need to check with the API if the username on the platform exists and if it can get information then start the MainActivity intent.

I do not know how to initially start the connection.

Comment: The login page is under SplashActivity

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LoginActivity` for checking if user already exists. Check this out in `onCreate()` (i think the best way keep this data in `SharedPreferences`). If user exists try to login and show `LoginActivity` with `ProgressBar`. If user does not exists simply show `Login/SignUpActivity`